# Joomla database connection error

Tags: php, joomla

I recently finished creating a website using Joomla 3x and now I am experiencing a problem trying to make it go live. I am having a problem with my sql database. I am getting this error **Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error**.  I searched this error and I found out that's a connectivity issue with the database and I had to do some changes in configuration.php, in which I did. I changed the values of $host, $user, $password, $db into the right ones but still I am experiencing the same thing but with a difference. I am getting this line as-well along with the other   **No database selected SQL=SELECT `session_id` FROM `n6hua_session` WHERE `session_id` = '5d1c6c10206ea4fbcdcc8dc9e4fe8002' LIMIT 0, 1**

Comment: Are you sure the database you're using for the value of `$db` actually exists? Any typos?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure. I have wrote it down again but with no result.

Comment: Try writing your own short PHP script to see if you can successfully connect to the MySQL server, select a database, and read a row from n6hua_session.

Comment: I did it and I can't connect. I am starting to thinking it's probably something with privileges.

Comment: Solved it. Even though I had all the privileges something was bugged. So I deleted the old database along with the user, made a new database and a user and imported the old database to the new one and it worked perfectly.